# How to test dynamic pages using cucumber in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I want to test page which has some header, text that comes from database. I want to write cucumber test to test such pages to see of the headings, text is correct as expected. 
E.g: On a page I have a section to display chart. This chart has header which is coming from database. I want to test a case to check if the header text is displayed properly as expected or not.

Comment: What is your question? Where you have a problem? Show us some code.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two approaches to this

1. Put what you expect in the test database first then test that your application show things correctly
2. Don't worry about the details of what is being displayed and just test that there is a visible placeholder for your content.

If your chart is complex and requires a lot of data then the first approach might be too difficult, so use the second approach. If the second approach doesn't provide sufficient testing for you, consider using other test tools, and other tests to proof your chart is correct e.g. your unit tests, your chart libraries unit tests etc.